# How to change the positions of buttons in Android Audio Capture example?

Tags: android, audio, android-linearlayout

I have been able to successfully set up the Android [Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)
example in my Eclipse.

But, in this part of the code:

```
ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
```

What do I need to do in order to place it at 20dp from top?
I also cannot understand what the role of "0" is.

I tried to find answers [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).
Other stackoverflow posts about adding button programmatically do not
answer my question and I do not have enough reputation to comment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

llParams.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);

ll.addView(mRecordButton, llParams);
```

Or you could try calling setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0) on mRecordButton before passing it into addView.

Comment: The 0 can be omitted, as there is an overloaded method available where you do not specify layout weight. You can read more about layout weights here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight

But modifying the value for that argument isn't going to help move your view down. It has to do with how much space your view will take in relationship to other views within a ViewGroup or Layout.